# WM_MOUSEWHEEL Stop scrolling?

Tags: c++, events, window, mouse

How do I know if the user, stop scrolling the mouse wheel? Currently, under my WinProc function, c++

```
 case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
if((int)wParam > 0)
  //scroll forward
else if((int)wParam < 0)
  //scroll backward
```

I look at the msdn site. I cant find event that will trigger if the mousewheel have stop.
How do I solve.

WM_MBUTTONUP, WM_MBUTTONDOWN handle clicking of the mousewheel.

Answer (score 1):

`WM_MOUSEWHEEL` messages are delivered for each discreet scroll event. When the user stops scrolling, the messages stop arriving. That's all there is to it.

Mouse wheel messages do not have any analogue to the mouse button down/up message pairs. That's because wheel scrolling is a fundamentally different action from button pressing.

Comment: Hmm. if that is the case, I just just reset the variable, every frame. but I scare the cycle of the cpu and my frame the different maybe cause unwanted result

Comment: I don't understand any of that. I don't know what your context is.